# why I can't change the string?

Tags: python

I want to change every `'0'` in the string to `'2'`,but it doesn't change at all.

```py
nums = ['0','0','1','1']
for ch in nums:
    if ch == '0':
        ch = '2'
    print(ch)
print(nums)
```

Comment: 1. `nums` is a list, not a string. 2. `ch = '2'` will only change the local variable `ch`. It is not bound in any way to the content of the `nums` list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how you modify array entries (by value), you can use indices instead:

```
for i, ch in enumerate(nums):
    if ch == '0':
        nums[i] = '2'
```

Answer (score 4):

variable `ch` in `for` loop is a separate entity which is not related to the list elements. You can use the following 1 liner list comprehension:

```
>>> nums = ['0','0','1','1']
>>> nums = [w.replace('0', '2') for w in nums]
>>> nums
['2', '2', '1', '1']
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

the `ch` variable simply contains the value of the item in the list.

You can do this with a list comprehension:

```
[ch if ch != '0' else '2' for ch in nums]
```

or with a for loop

```
nums = ['0','0','1','1']
new_nums = []
for ch in nums:
    if ch == '0':
        new_nums.append('2')
    else
        new_nums.append(ch)
```

Answer (score 1):

You update the variable `ch` value instead of update the list value with the reference of `index`.

Need to update the list value with reference of index value.

```
nums = ['0','0','1','1']
for ch in range(0,len(nums)):
    if nums[ch] == '0':
        nums[ch] = '2'
print(nums)
```

Output :

```
['2', '2', '1', '1']
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable ‘ch’ is local to for-loop and only ‘pull out’ info from nums, changing value on it doesn’t change elements inside list.

Try this:

```
For index, ch in enumerate(nums):
if ch == ‘0’:
    nums[index] = ‘2’
```